# QueryFailure flag was could not find cursor in cache

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-query

I got the following error while i was listing `MyCollection` all documents:

> MongoDB.Driver.MongoQueryException: QueryFailure flag was could not
>   find cursor in cache for id 5389104123286064734 over MyCollection
>   (response was { "$err" : "could not find cursor in cache for id
>   5389104123286064734 over collection MyCollection", "code" : 16336 })

MyCollection holds about 24000 documents and I'm using MongoDB driver for C#

Note: I got this exception sometimes, I did the same action again and it respond properly!!

Could you please explain this error, what is the possible causes, how to avoid it ?

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error means the cursor doesn't exist on the server. This could be for a couple of reasons.

Background: mongodb uses cursors and a cursor id to keep track of where you are in your result set. It does not stream all documents for your query all at once, but rather it sends them in batches. After iterating a complete batch, the driver will send back an OP_GETMORE to get the next batch.

Possibles issues:

1. You are taking over 10 minutes to iterate the results of a single batch. Cursors timeout after 10 minutes. Best way to solve this is to specify a smaller batch size, say 20 documents per batch.
2. You are hitting mongos behind a load balancer that does not use ip affinity. If the load balancer recieves the OP_GETMORE request on a different connection than the original query, then it might send the OP_GETMORE to a different server.

Comment: You could also increase (or disable) the timeout, can't you?

Comment: Thank you for your great reply. I tried the the first solution, set batch size with 50 but it gives the same error, and then i tried with 20 it takes too much time to response! 
I'm not sure if the second case is the reason , do you have any idea how to handle it?

Comment: @I3arnon I tried to disable timeout for cursor it works , but I'm wondering is there any disadvantages to increase/disable cursor timeout?

Comment: @MohamedFarrag Yes there are. In the real case of a timeout (your process crashed, or had a mishandled exception) the cursor would never close an hang on forever. I wouldn't recommend disabling the timeout unless you're sure you're doing it right. Increasing the timeout would be better...

Comment: Unfortunately, the 10 minute timeout is not configurable. It's either 10 minutes or no timeout at all. Which is why decreasing the batch size is effectively the same thing; less come back, client-side iterates them quicker, sends getmore to the server quicker, refreshing the timeout quicker. I'm not sure why a lower batch size would take longer to respond - that doesn't make sense.  BTW: are you hitting an index for your query?

Comment: Ok In fact after I increased the timeout it worked for a while but failed again!, so I contact the support and they told me that something went wrong to load balancer. Any ways thank you guys for your precious, information much appreciated :)

Comment: The solution for me was to add an index to the column I was sorting on.